# `std::bitset` with and without boundary checks

Tags: c++, performance, stl, bitset

And again about STL `std::bitset` - its documentation says that functions `set/reset/test` do boundary checks, and `operator[]` doesn't. My timing experiments show that functions `set/test` typically perform 2-3% faster than the `operator[]`. The code I'm working with is:

```
typedef unsigned long long U64;
const U64 MAX = 800000000ULL;

struct Bitmap1
{
  void insert(U64 N) {this->s[N % MAX] = 1;}
  bool find(U64 N) const {return this->s[N % MAX];}
private:
  std::bitset<MAX> s;  // <---- takes MAX/8 memory (in bytes)
};

struct Bitmap2
{
  void insert(U64 N) {this->s.set(N % MAX);}
  bool find(U64 N) const {return this->s.test(N % MAX);}
private:
  std::bitset<MAX> s;  // <---- takes MAX/8 memory (in bytes)
};

int main()
{
  Bitmap2* s = new Bitmap2();
  // --------------------------- storing
  const size_t t0 = time(0);
  for (unsigned k = 0; k < LOOPS; ++k)
  {
    for (U64 i = 0; i < MAX; ++i) s->insert(i);
  }
  cout << "storing: " << time(0) - t0 << endl;
  // -------------------------------------- search
  const size_t t1 = time(0);
  U64 count = 0;
  for (unsigned k = 0; k < LOOPS; ++k)
  {
    for (U64 i = 0; i < MAX; ++i) if (s->find(i)) ++count;
  }
  cout << "search:  " << time(0) - t1 << endl;
  cout << count << endl;
}
```

How to explain this? Absence of boundary checks should save us some cycles, right?

```
Compiler: g++ 4.8.1 (options -g -O4)
VMware VM: Ubuntu 3.11.0-15
Host: MacBook Pro
```

Comment: It might be benchmark fault. Please post complete example.

Comment: What specific experiments were you doing? Can you show us what you tried, what compiler and compiler flags you were using, and the results?

Comment: OK, I'll add the what is in the main function

Comment: @AlekseyYakovlev: `Bitset::operator[]` must create and use a proxy.  `Bitset::Set` needs do no such thing.  I'd expect that `Set` is actually _far_ faster, but the difference is lost due to the caching of assigning 100MB of data.

Comment: Wait, I take it back.  The difference is lost because you call `rand()` every iteration, which is REALLY slow

Comment: can you compile with `g++ -O3` (inlinging enabled) and rerun the benchmark?

Comment: @bobah: I had no idea that `-O2` didn't do inlining or loop unrolling!  I can't imagine why people recommend that over `-O3`!

Comment: @Mooing Duck - I have to work with large bitsets (100MB is actually kinda small for me) and VM has 12GB of core memory, so why should I care about caching? I change only Bitmap implementation, caching and rand calls are exactly the same in both cases

Comment: As for `-O3` - I ran the test a couple of times, and now performance of Bitmap1 and Bitmap2 is exactly the same. I'd like to hear about somebody else experiments with this small piece of code, and on real Unix, not VM.

Comment: Using a bitset is so cheap that your test is completely dominated by rand and even the % operator which is actually a division which is insanely slow. This means that your benchmark is very sensitive to the compiler changing stuff about non-relevant code. You are not benchmarking in a valid way. Fix the benchmark first.

Comment: @AlekseyYakovlev: Yes, the `rand()` is the same in each, but the program is spending ~90% of the time calculating rand, ~6% of the time doing division, and ~4% of the time doing bitsets, which means `Set` is really ~35% faster, not 3%.  (All numbers estimated up and not to be used for any purposes)

Comment: Also, by caching I didn't mean to disk, I mean going all the way to the core memory.  That's a long way!

Comment: @usr and others - thank you for your observations, I didn't think about this percentage. I'll modify the test...

Comment: Well, I've removed rand() calls and division by module, I've reduced the bitset size to 1000 bytes, but still I don't see any difference between `set/test` and `operator[]` performance. I'll update the original question

Comment: @MooingDuck - `-O3` disproportionally slows down the compilation and enables optimizations which may not necessarily speed each particular application up

Comment: @bobah: I rather think inlining would be a HUGE speed boost in any application, wouldn't it?  I'll have to do tests.

Comment: @MooingDuck - I mean second order effects resulting from the binary size explosive growth, formulated here http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7269

Comment: @bobah: That article doesn't mention "explosive growth", it says "if the size of the image exceeds the size of the available instruction cache, severe performance penalties can be observed."  Unfortunately, this article doesn't mention that inlining can sometimes make code _smaller_, which gives the performance benefits of fewer opcodes _and_ better cache performance, especially with `std::` code.  You can use the `-finline-limit=n` flag to make sure you get the best performance.

Comment: @Mooing Duck - _explosive_ is my personal observation, both compilation time and binary size grow a lot with `-O3` on GCC (when building several M lines projects)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I remove `rand`, division, output, and the memory cache from the timings:

```
bool bracket_test() {
    std::bitset<MAX> s;
    for(int j=0; j<num_iterations; ++j) {
        for(int i=0; i<MAX; ++i)
            s[i] = !s[MAX-1-i];
    }
    return s[0];
}
bool set_test() {
    std::bitset<MAX> s;
    for(int j=0; j<num_iterations; ++j) {
        for(int i=0; i<MAX; ++i)
            s.set(i, !s.test(MAX-1-i));
    }
    return s.test(0);
}
bool no_test() {
    bool s = false;
    for(int j=0; j<num_iterations; ++j) {
        for(int i=0; i<MAX; ++i)
            s = !s;
    }
    return s;
}
```

I get these results with Clang at http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cdc832bfcc7e32be.  (I do 10000 iterations, 20 times, and measure the lowest time, which mitigates timing errors.)

```
clang++ -std=c++11  -O0 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -pthread main.cpp  && ./a.out
bracket_test took 178663845 ticks to find result 1
set_test     took 117336632 ticks to find result 1
no_test      took 9214297 ticks to find result 0
clang++ -std=c++11  -O1 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -pthread main.cpp  && ./a.out
bracket_test took 798184780 ticks to find result 1
set_test     took 565999680 ticks to find result 1
no_test      took 41693575 ticks to find result 0
clang++ -std=c++11  -O2 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -pthread main.cpp  && ./a.out
bracket_test took 81240369 ticks to find result 1
set_test     took 72172912 ticks to find result 1
no_test      took 41907685 ticks to find result 0
clang++ -std=c++11  -O3 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -pthread main.cpp  && ./a.out
bracket_test took 77688054 ticks to find result 1
set_test     took 72433185 ticks to find result 1
no_test      took 41433010 ticks to find result 0
```

Previous versions of this test found that brackets were slightly faster, but now that I've improved the accuracy of the timings, it appears that my margin of error for timing is approximately 3%.  At O1 `Set` is 35-54% faster, at O2 it's 13-49% faster, and at O3 it's 2-34% faster.  This seems pretty conclusive to me, aside from looking at the assembly output.

So here's assembly (at `GCC -O`) via http://assembly.ynh.io/:

```
std::bitset<MAX> s
s[1000000] = true;
return s;

0000 4889F8         movq    %rdi, %rax
0003 4889FA         movq    %rdi, %rdx
0006 488D8F00       leaq    100000000(%rdi), %rcx
     E1F505
000d 48C70200       movq    $0, (%rdx)
     000000
0014 4883C208       addq    $8, %rdx
0018 4839CA         cmpq    %rcx, %rdx
001b 75F0           jne .L2
001d 48838848       orq $1, 125000(%rax)
     E8010001 
0025 C3             ret
```

and

```
std::bitset<MAX> s;
s.set(1000000);
return s;

0026 4889F8         movq    %rdi, %rax
0029 4889FA         movq    %rdi, %rdx
002c 488D8F00       leaq    100000000(%rdi), %rcx
     E1F505
0033 48C70200       movq    $0, (%rdx)
     000000
003a 4883C208       addq    $8, %rdx
003e 4839CA         cmpq    %rcx, %rdx
0041 75F0           jne .L6
0043 48838848       orq $1, 125000(%rax)
     E8010001 
004b C3             ret
```

I can't really read assembly so well, but these are completely identical, so analysis of this case is easy.  If the compiler knows they're both in range, it optimizes out the range check.  When I replace the fixed index with a variable index, `Set` adds 5 operations to check for the boundary case.

As for REASONS that `Set` is faster sometimes, is that `operator[]` has to do a TON of work for the reference proxy that `Set` doesn't have to do.  The reason that `Set` is slower sometimes is that the proxy is trivially inlined, in which case the only difference is that `Set` has to do the boundary check.  On the other hand, `Set` only has to do the boundary check if the compiler cannot prove that indexes are always in range.  So it depends on the surrounding code, a lot.  Your results may differ.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/set says:

> Sets the bit at position pos to the value value.
>   Throws std::out_of_range if pos does not correspond to a valid position within the bitset.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/operator_at says:

> Accesses the bit at position pos. Returns an object of type std::bitset::reference that allows modification of the value.
>   Unlike test(), does not throw exceptions: the behavior is undefined if pos is out of bounds.

and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/reference says:

> The std::bitset class includes std::bitset::reference as a publicly-accessible nested class. This class is used as a proxy object to allow users to interact with individual bits of a bitset, since standard C++ types (like references and pointers) are not built with enough precision to specify individual bits. The primary use of std::bitset::reference is to provide an l-value that can be returned from operator[]. Any reads or writes to a bitset that happen via a std::bitset::reference potentially read or write to the entire underlying bitset.

It should be clear that `operator[]` actually has a lot more to it than is intuitive.

Comment: So, the bottom line is - we shouldn't expect that `operator[]` is **always** faster than `set/test`, right? If yes, that should go into some wide-known doc about `std::bitset` I think

Comment: @AlekseyYakovlev: the relative performance of `operator[]` vs `Set` is, like everything else in C++, implementation defined.

Comment: @MooingDuck - well, I disagree. If program logic allows a STL user to avoid boundary checks, then [s]he shouldn't be taxed for that on any optimization level.

Comment: @AlekseyYakovlev: It's interesting that GCC doesn't seem to be optimizing `operator[]` properly, but clang does.  I wonder what MSVC does.  `operator[]` is _intended_ to be the way to avoid boundary checks, bug GCC doesn't seem to be making that viable.

Comment: @AlekseyYakovlev: I did more accurate timing tests, and accounted for some variance.  This time it appears that `Set` is indeed faster, at all optimization levels.

Comment: @MooingDuck - thanks! So, my original experiments had some meaning

Comment: @AlekseyYakovlev: Well, these tests were with `clang`.  When I checked the assembly from `GCC`, they're identical when the compiler can prove the indexes cannot be out of range.

Comment: It may be worth updating this answer; nowadays, it does seem like O3 makes bracket_test faster than set_test.